# Remover tags dentro de tag usando Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Preciso remover todas as tags span dentro das tags p mantendo seu conteudo.

Codigo html:

```
<p>Conceito <span>e</span> <span>Signi</span>ficado<span> </span>de <span>Tex</span>to.</p>

<p><span>Geralmente</span>, entendemos <span>o</span> texto como um <span>conjunto</span> de frases</p>
```

Resultado esperado:

```
<p>Conceito e Significado de Texto.</p>

<p>Geralmente, entendemos o texto como um conjunto de frases.<p>
```

Comment: O que tentou fazer e qual foi o resultado obtido?

Comment: Testei um for i in soup.find_all('p'): e usei um método de remover tags span mantendo o texto porem o resultado é que  não altera no soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
linha1 = "<p>Conceito <span>e</span> <span>Signi</span>ficado<span> </span>de <span>Tex</span>to.</p>"
linha2 = "<p><span>Geralmente</span>, entendemos <span>o</span> texto como um <span>conjunto</span> de frases</p>"

linha1 = linha1.replace('<span>','').replace('</span>','')
linha2 = linha2.replace('<span>','').replace('</span>','')

print(linha1)
print(linha2)
```